# managed_file upload clearing $form_state

Tags: 7, forms, ajax

I am having an annoying problem whereby $form_state['values']['region'] and $form_state['values']['country'] are being cleared when I upload an image via the managed_file field. This is causing a "...tid cannot be null" error upon DB insertion (of course because the values are now null after managed_file upload). If I disable the managed_file field everything works as it should but of course I need the upload!

I am relatively new to Drupal and thus not quite understanding why this is acting like it is. Can anyone help me out as this is driving me nuts!

**My form**

```
function myforms_company_add_form($form, &$form_state, $node) {

  $form['#prefix'] = '<div id="wrapper">';
  $form['#suffix'] = '</div>';

  if(!isset($form_state['values']['region']) && !isset($form_state['values']['country'])) {
      $selectedRegion = array_shift(taxonomy_get_parents($node->field_company_region['und'][0]['tid']))->tid;    
      $selectedCountry = $node->field_company_region['und'][0]['tid'];
    }
    else {
        $selectedRegion = $form_state['values']['region'];    
        $selectedCountry = $form_state['values']['country'];
    }

$form['region'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Region'),
    '#type' => 'select',
    '#required' => TRUE,
    '#options' => _get_region_list('region'),
    '#prefix' => '<div id="contact-selector"><div id="region-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div>',
    '#default_value' => $selectedRegion,
    '#ajax' => array(
      'callback' => 'region_ajax_callback',
      'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
     ),
  ); 

  $form['country']['wrapper'] = array(
    '#type' => 'markup',
    '#prefix' => '<div id="country-wrapper">',
    '#suffix' => '</div></div>',
  );

  if (isset($selectedRegion)) {
    $form['country'] = array(
        '#title' => t('Country'),
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#required' => TRUE,
        '#options' => _get_country_list($selectedRegion),
        '#default_value' => $selectedCountry,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'callback' => 'region_ajax_callback',
            'wrapper' => 'wrapper',
        ),
      );
   }

  $form['company_logo'] = array(
    '#title' => t('Logo'),
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://my-files/',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    '#default_value' => $node->field_company_logo['und'][0]['fid'],
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
    '#prefix' => '<hr>',
  );

  return $form;

}
```

**Then my callback**

```
function region_ajax_callback($form, &$form_state) { 
  return $form;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I recently encountered the same problem. I found that data is erased in function - drupal_validate_form(). I have not fully understood why this is happening, therefore, just went bypassed the problem. I have rewritten my code so that the code section that erased the data in drupal_validate_form() is not executed.

My code:

```
  $managed_file_processing_fn = array_merge(
    element_info_property('managed_file', '#process', array()),
    array('ccw_managed_file_process')
  );

  $form['customization']['main']['request_design']['upload_design'] = array(
    '#type' => 'managed_file',
    '#progress_indicator' => 'bar',
    '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    '#upload_validators' => array(
      'file_validate_extensions' => array('jpg jpeg gif png zip rar tar'),
    ),
    '#states' => array(
      'visible' => array(
        ':input[name="type_of_upload"]' => array(
          array('value' => strval(CCW_GET_HELP)),
        ),
      ),
    ),
    '#process' => $managed_file_processing_fn,
    '#default_value' => $upload_design,
  );

/**
 * Process managed_file.
 */
function ccw_managed_file_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  // When AJAX is execute we ignore form validation.
  $element['upload_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = FALSE;
  $element['remove_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = FALSE;

  return $element;
}
```

Topic with the same problem on drupal.org:
https://www.drupal.org/node/2311199

Also, I noticed that in Drupal 8 the behavior is the same.

Answer (score 0):

Have modified function from the previous example. Filtering of non-empty values for `#limit_validation_errors` prevents validation errors of required but empty fields, and passes all non-empty values in `form_state`

```
function ccw_managed_file_process($element, &$form_state, $form) {
  $limit_validation_errors = array_map(
    function ($value) {
      return [$value];
    },
    array_keys(array_filter($form_state['values']))
  );
  // When AJAX is execute we ignore form validation.
  $element['upload_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = $limit_validation_errors;
  $element['remove_button']['#limit_validation_errors'] = $limit_validation_errors;


  return $element;
}
```